# NSPredicate for filtering array

Tags: swift, nspredicate

I am stuck on sorting in the array.

I want to sort array by name:

```
var mesta: NSArray = ["ceska lipa", "budejovice", "liptakov"]
var zkouska = "lip"

let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF contains %@", zkouska)
print(mesta.filter{ predicate.evaluate(with: $0)})
```

It prints **[ceska lipa, liptakov]**, but I want to liptakov first, because letters *lip* are earlier than *ceska lipa*

I want result [liptakov, ceska lipa]

I tried:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF BEGINSWITH %@", zkouska)
```

but it prints only *liptakov*

Comment: Predicates are for *filtering.* Use `sort()` for sorting.

Comment: sorry I meant filtering

Comment: Don't use `NSArray`. Use a Swift array.

Comment: *"but I want to liptakov first"* – that is sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var mesta = ["ceska lipa", "budejovice", "liptakov"]
var zkouska = "lip"

let filtered = mesta.filter { $0.contains(zkouska) }
let sorted = filtered.sorted {
    return $0.range(of: zkouska)!.lowerBound < $1.range(of: zkouska)!.lowerBound
}

print(sorted) // ["liptakov", "ceska lipa"]
```

Comment: as an exercise for the reader, updating the code to ignore diacritics and case. The  names of the cities should actually be `["Česká Lípa", "Budějovice", "Liptákov"]` :)